# Better way to iterate over df and set another column value than iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate over df rows and basing on two columns assign a new value to one of them or add new value to a new column.
I am able to do that with iterrows() but I have read it is not recommended approach.

Data looks like this:

```
name   xfactor    t_age    height
Jack    NaN        24      180    
John    NaN        26      178
```

And I use this code to have things done:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        df.at[i, 't_age'] = row['t_age'] * row['height']
    except SomeException:
        df.at[i, 'xfactor'] = 1
```

expected output could look like this:

```
name   xfactor    t_age    height
Jack    NaN       4320     180    
John     1         26      178
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Where did you read that `iterrows()` is not the recommended approach for iterating over the rows and what is the rationale given?

Comment: Why is the second row supposed to error-out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `iterrows()` is not recommended. You can use `itertuples()` instead.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
        try:
            df.at[row.Index, 't_age'] = row.t_age * row.height
        except SomeException:
            df.at[row.Index, 'xfactor'] = 1
```

Comment: @Goyo Iam afraid I don't get you.. `row.Index` returns index numbers and not strings. I have tested this code myself and it runs much faster than using `iterrows()`

Comment: @Goyo oh now i get it... sorry my bad... i will edit it... by tested it i meant that i have used this many times. But I missed the right hand side of the assignment operation...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong then what about this?

```
df['new_column'] = df['t_age'] * df['height']
```

Comment: What about exception? I am afraid your solution does not cover that.

Comment: same question: Why is the second row supposed to error-out?

Comment: invalid input data can be the cause

Comment: @maslak [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html).